# Python KIVY: select the correct ID

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to access child id (in kv file) from python code.
I know that it's possible to simply give as parameter the text to print but this is not my real code so I need to be able to select any child id.

debug.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.current = "screen_A"



class Menu_A(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu_A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def action(self):
        print(self.manager.ids.menu_a.box_2.box_2a.btn.text)


Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

debug.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:

    Menu_A:
        name: "screen_A"
        id: menu_a

        BoxLayout:
            id: box_1

        BoxLayout:
            id: box_2

            BoxLayout:
                id: box_2a

                Button:
                    id: btn
                    text: "print me"
                    on_press: root.ids.menu_a.action()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Access text using ObjectProperty

In the example, we used an ObjectProperty to hook up to the button to access the text because an id is a weakref to the widget. ***Using ObjectProperty creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit***. It is generally regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty.

## MyScreenManager Class

By default, the first screen added into the ScreenManager will be
displayed. Therefore, no need to overload the __init__ method and set the first screen to be displayed.

## Example

The following example illustrates accessing the button's text using an ObjectProperty and self.ids in two separate print statements.

### debug.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Menu_A(Screen):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu_A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def action(self):
        print("Using self.obj.text={}".format(self.obj.text))    # using an ObjectProperty
        print("Using self.ids.btn.text={}".format(self.ids.btn.text))    # using self.ids


Builder.load_file("debug.kv")


class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

### debug.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:

    Menu_A:
        name: "screen_A"
        id: menu_a

<Menu_A>:
    obj: btn
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_1

    BoxLayout:
        id: box_2

        BoxLayout:
            id: box_2a

            Button:
                id: btn
                text: "print me"
                on_press: root.manager.ids.menu_a.action()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]
[image: Figure 2 - Clicked Button]

Comment: Thank you. How do you do the same (using ObjectProperty) buy with only python ? (and only one button to simplify)

Answer (score 0):

Your btn is in the ids of your manager so you can directly access him with:

```
def action(self):
    print(self.manager.ids.btn.text)
```

And in your kv you can use `menu_a` instead of `root.ids.menu_a`